# Create an anonymous function object from a constructor and store it in another object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following function being stored in JSON data:

```
function (e) { e.preventDefault();var caro=$(e.target).parents('.carousel');curr=$(caro).parents('.grid-stack-item');currInt=$(curr).find('.carousel-indicators li.active').data('slide-to');$(curr).find('.carousel-indicators li.active').removeClass('active');currInt+=1;var currLi=$(curr).find('.carousel-indicators li')[currInt];$(currLi).addClass('active');$(caro).carousel(1);$(caro).carousel('pause');var tr=$(e.target).closest('tr');data=this.dataItem(tr);wizard(1,$(e.target).parents('.grid-stack-item'),data); }
```

I am using an external library which requires the function in the JSON string to be attached to an object property as a JS function.

Literally, the code looks like this:

```
grid({
    click: data.functionData
)};
```

The issue I'm having is the data.functionData is being evaluated as a string and when the click event is executed on the grid object it results as an error as the data should be a function and not a string.

What I need to do is create an anonymous function...

```
var anonFun = new Function();
```

And takes an event as a parameter....

```
function (e) { }
```

Then attach it to the click event in the grid...

```
grid({ click: function (e) { //dostuff } });
```

I'm close to accomplishing this, however my issue right now is I do not know how to give an anonymous function created with a function constructor the parameter 'e'.

To give my current state literally, my code is...

```
var jsonData = "function (e) { e.preventDefault();var caro=$(e.target).parents('.carousel');curr=$(caro).parents('.grid-stack-item');currInt=$(curr).find('.carousel-indicators li.active').data('slide-to');$(curr).find('.carousel-indicators li.active').removeClass('active');currInt+=1;var currLi=$(curr).find('.carousel-indicators li')[currInt];$(currLi).addClass('active');$(caro).carousel(1);$(caro).carousel('pause');var tr=$(e.target).closest('tr');data=this.dataItem(tr);wizard(1,$(e.target).parents('.grid-stack-item'),data); }";

var anonFunc = new Function(jsonData);

grid({ click: anonFunc )};
```

I think I need to do something like:

```
var anonFunc = new Function(e, jsonData);
```

And change jsonData to be solely the inner contents of the function.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like one approach.  You should be able to strip the `function (e) {` and trailing `}` off easily enough in order to do so, or change your JSON string to not have them in the first place?

Comment: (Function (e){})("this is passed as e"); ...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't make sense of it at the time, but by stripping my JSON data to only be the function contents I was able to use the function constructor to create a function object and attach it to my click event handler.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

```
var anonFunc = new Function('e', data.functionContentsData);

grid({ click: anonFun )};
```